# Chinese django translations not working

Tags: django, django-i18n

My settings.py looks like this:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    #Simplified Chinese
    ('zh-hans', _('Simplified Chinese')),
)
```

In my template I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
```

and

```
<button type="submit" value="zh-hans" name='language'>{% trans 'Simplified Chinese' %}</button>
```

And in my urls.py I have:

```
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
```

In my po file I have:

```
msgid "Menu"
msgstr "菜单"
```

I compiled the messages but it doesn't work. I have working translations for french so I don't understand what is going on with the Chinese translations.

EDIT: So I tried to put the Chinese translation for "Menu" into my french po file because I thought it might be the characters themselves but it worked. Then When I put it back into the Chinese po file, "Menu" didn't get translated.

Comment: You are mixing `javascript-catalog` translations with the regular ones! Which is not working? When you press the button you want the language to change?

Comment: So when I click the button I see the language names change but in my po file I haven't set any of those translations. But like I said in my post, when I click the button Menu doesn't change to what I have it set to in the po file. I have the exact same thing for french and it works.

Comment: Just for the records: You have run `compilemessages`, right? Another thing I would like you to do: Add another language, say `de` and check if that's working.

Comment: I tired de and it worked and yes I ran compilemessages. It seems tothat Chinese is the only language not working

Comment: Hmm... I guess so. That's weird. Maybe someone else here will be able to solve this issue as I am not familiar with this language :(

Comment: I found a fix... see my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those of you having the same issue, the solution I found is to create the locale folder with an underscore and a capital H.

So it would look like:

```
django-admin makemessages -l zh_Hans
```

The reason is that the Django documentation [states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations):

> In all cases the name of the directory containing the translation is
>   expected to be named using locale name notation. E.g. de, pt_BR,
>   es_AR, etc.

and in [another part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/) says:

> A locale name, either a language specification of the form ll or a
>   combined language and country specification of the form ll_CC.
>   Examples: it, de_AT, es, pt_BR. The language part is always in lower
>   case and the country part in upper case. The separator is an
>   underscore.

Comment: I has struggle with this and figured this out also. Directory name have to be zh_Hans, and settings file zh-hans. But if you make messages with current setup, django makes translation files for zh-hans directory also. So when making messages you should use command django-admin makemessages -l zh_Hans

Answer (score 0):

Is your chinesse locale directory named 'zh_hans' instead of 'zh-hans'? I believe the directory must have underscore instead of dash.

Comment: I'll give that a shot

Comment: Don't forget to remake messagges, re run everything, just in case.

Comment: See my answer above, you were on the right track. I assume this is a bug? I'm not entirely sure why it works

Answer (score 0):

This issue indeed confused me a lot!
Here's a short summary base on ALUW's answer:

```py
# in settings.py, use lower-case language code, The separator is a dash.
LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), )
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    #Simplified Chinese
    ('zh-hans', _('Simplified Chinese')),
)
```

```sh
# while when making and compiling message file, use local name.
# The language part is always in lower case and the country part in upper case. 
# The separator is an underscore.

./manage.py makemessages -l zh_Hans
```